# Unsolved Elementary Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

I am currently in Integral Calculus, and I wondered if I could get a little creative with my practice. I was curious if there were any unsolved, but rather simple (solvable using methods taught in calc I/II), so that I could be practicing the integration tehniques I have learned while also solving a problem that hasn't been solved yet.

I have consulted lists of integrals, but those are in a more general form (constants are represented by letters, etc.), and I was wondering if there was a place I could find lists of indefinite integrals that had never been calculated but weren't that difficult.

Also, on a side note, if you happen to know any good resources for reading about more techniques of integration, I am currently looking to expand my "toolbox" of integration methods.

Thank you all, and I hope each and every one of you is having a nice day.

Comment: Try (one of my favorites for calc I/II, it uses a trick that not many students are aware off): $$\int \frac{1}{a-\sin(x)}dx, \quad a<1$$

Comment: This is more advanced http://advancedintegrals.com/advanced-integration-techniques.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure how one would even go about compiling a list of simple integrals that haven't been solved yet. Say I have an unsolved integral. In order to add it to the list, I would need to also verify that it has a simple solution. If I succeed, the problem stops being unsolved, but if I fail then the problem stops being simple! ;)

Comment: @Rebellos I will work on that next chance I get :)

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Just from reading the introduction, I can tell I will be referring to this quite often :) thank you

Comment: @DavidH That paradox of sorts had gone unnoticed to me until you pointed it out, but now that I think about it, it makes perfect sense. I guess if I wanted to complete a "new" elementary integral I would first have to prove it was elementary.. thank you for your insight though, it would have taken me longer to have that revelation

Comment: @Rebellos For $a=1$ there is a really elementary "cheat" and a very quick solution. But for $a<1$, I can't see a way other than a targent half angle substitution (Weierstrass sub). And I got the answer but it's tedious, involving partial fractions. Is there a better "trick"?

Comment: @Rebellos For what it's worth I get $\displaystyle \int \frac 1{a-\sin x} dx = \frac 1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\ln \frac{a\tan\frac x2-1-\sqrt{1-a^2}} { a\tan\frac x2-1+\sqrt{1-a^2}} +c$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [relevant flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ObiW.png), because as Silvanus P Thompson said:

> "Here note this very remarkable fact, that we could not have integrated in the above case [$y = a\log_c x + C$] if we had not happened to know the corresponding differentiation. If no one had found out that differentiating $\log_c x$ gave $x^{-1}$, we [would] have been utterly stuck by the problem [of] how to integrate $x^{-1} dx$. Indeed it should be frankly admitted that this is one of the curious features of the integral calculus :- that you can't integrate anything before the reverse process of differentiating something else has yielded that expression which you want to integrate."
>   Calculus Made Easy, p199.

Integration, being a inverse process, is much less systematic than differentiation.

EDIT Right after that quote the author gives an 'unsolved, but rather simple' integral. It may not be solvable though - that quality doesn't necessarily follow from simplicity when it comes to integration.

Comment: I agree with what you said in the edit.. That is an interesting flow chart though, and it does well to provide a more systematic approach to integration. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some texts that cover the various techniques of integration at a level comparable to Calculus I and II (and a bit beyond) include:

1. The Soviet text *Problems in Mathematical Analysis* edited by Boris Demidovich has many problems using the various techniques of integration to solve. A few of the techniques Demidovich gives are not usually found elsewhere.
2. Joseph Edwards’ *A Treatise on the Integral Calculus* (Volume 1) is a particularly valuable source for many interesting integrals, and being published before 1923, is out of copyright meaning it can be readily found online.
3. Michael Spivak’s *Calculus* contains many interesting questions that use integration, like the proof that $\pi$ is irrational for example.
4. While it is a bit old, G. H. Hardy’s *A Course of Pure Mathematics*, is also a useful source for questions, and being published before 1923 means it too is no longer under copyright.
5. The recent text *How to Integrate It: A Practical Guide to Solving Elementary Integrals* by  Seán M. Stewart has individual chapters devoted to a particular technique of integration, with each being accompanied by a wealth of end-of-chapter exercises.

Comment: Thank you, I will refer back here plenty I am sure :)